# Faster Python Sorting Implementation

Tags: python

Not a Python guy--trying to implement this sort faster. Currently I have a hash that includes objects, and I'm sorting them on a call to a method on those objects. I'm not certain how sorted() is functioning--is this making multiple method calls per comparison? Would I be better off perhaps storing the method call on the hash itself and sorting on that?

```
sorted(hash_object.items(), key=lambda x:x[1].method_call_here())
```

Currently taking ~100-400ms which is a fairly slow sort. Thoughts?

Responding to what the method call is here; I'm skeptical that it's the method. It's a direct port of my Ruby implementation which runs at 0.2ms, but maybe it's slower in Python for some reason. Really simple method though. It's calling the track quality method below:

```
class Track:

  def __init__(self, title, play_count, track_number):
    self.title = title
    self.play_count = play_count
    self.track_number = track_number

  def predicted_listens(self):
    return 1/self.track_number

  def track_quality(self):
    return self.play_count/self.predicted_listens()
```

For reference, it would seem like it's implementing something identical to the Ruby source:

```
self.sort_by { |track| track.quality }
```

My guess is I'm wrong about what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. No way the Ruby sort should be 500 times faster. Roughly how many items are we talking about?

Comment: Is this Python2 ro Python3? `1/self.track_number` will be truncated if `self.track_number` is an `int` in Python2

Comment: On this old computer, I get about 148ms to sort 100000 items. Is that in the right ball park?

Comment: Are you sure your comparison is fair? It seems like you're comparing wrong things, your ruby code sorts a list of values by a value property, your python code sorts a list of tuples by a property of one tuple. The python code includes an additional convert of dict to list of tuples and an additional tuple lookup in the comparison key.

Comment: Also, if using Python2, change `hash_object.items()` to `hash_object.iteritems()`.

Comment: Folks are correct that this is running faster than I initially clocked (it was 3am and I was measuring from the wrong point in the code). I get similar times to the Ruby on remeasuring. Also, Killian, thanks for pointing this out; my Python chops are admittedly quite messy.

Answer (score 2):

No it's just calling the method once per item. The deprecated `cmp=` would get called for each comparison.

You could try profiling it, but most likely the method_call is the cpu hog compared to the sort.

Perhaps you can post the code of `method_call_here` to see if it can be improved.

Comment: edited with the method call; appreciate the quick feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

If `track_number` is not going to change, it might be worth making `predicted_listens` a class member and setting its value in the `__init__` function (and anywhere else it changes) to avoid calculating it while sorting. This may improve the sort performance.

```
  def __init__(self, title, play_count, track_number):
    self.title = title
    self.play_count = play_count
    self.track_number = track_number
    self.predicted_listens = 1/self.track_number
```

Comment: For that matter, track_quality need not be a method either, but can also be computed in `__init__`.